# retrieving var from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm visiting a link to my Node app called

```
http://localhost:5000/payment?issue=123456
```

In my node app i have a callback that is fired when this happens

```
app.get('/payment', function(req, res){
  res.render('payment', { user: req.user });
});
```

how do i get the issue number (123456) and assign it to a variable in the node app?

Comment: [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL params, you can use a module called "url",

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

As an Express only alternative you can use the `req.query` method

```
app.get('/payment', function(req, res){
  issue = req.query.issue;
  // Other stuff
});
```